# One fragment is being drawn on top of another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments, One for a game and one for the score.
When I'm moving from the game fragment to the score fragment it works great, but when I'm trying to move back to the game it draws both fragments on the same container (even when using the remove function).

```
        public void nextLvl(Fragment current, Fragment next, String score, String nextTag, int LvlTime){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("scoreKey", score);
        args.putInt("levelTime", LvlTime);
        next.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm != null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(current);
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_place, next, nextTag);
            ft.commit();
            Log.d("FM","MOVED TO "+next.toString());
        }else{
            Log.d("FM","fm is null");
        }
  }
```

This the code I use to move between fragments.

Here's an image to demonstrate what I mean in "being drawn on top of each other":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yrrb.png

1 = Game fragment.

2 = Score fragment.

3 = Result of moving from Score fragment to Game fragment.

Comment: I had a similar problem once. I was using fragment as an attribute in my xml file and tried to add a fragment into that.
I changed from fragment to FrameLayout in my xml and everything worked fine.
So what kind of attribute are your "R.id.fragment_place"?

Comment: @Furedal It's a fragment. I'll change it to FrameLayout and try again, I'll update you if it worked or didn't.

Edit:
Didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: You should upload all relevant code for when you are switching fragments if we should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use replace fragment instead of add

example:

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, next, nextTag);
        ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ft.replace` instead of `remove()` and `add()`

example:

```
ft.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
```

Comment: Still draws it on top of the other one :\